# Unable to generate refresh token for IBM Visual Recognition API

Tags: visual-recognition

I am trying to work with IAM token based authentication. I am able to generate 'access token' and could do operations using the 'access token'. Now I am having issue while generating 'refresh token'. I am following this link https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/watson?topic=watson-iam.

I am using below command to generate refresh token. Here Authorization header value obtained using username as 'apikey' and value as my key. {refreh-token} value I am using which I received while generating 'access token'.

`curl -k -X POST --header "Authorization: Basic Yng6Yng=" --data-urlencode "grant_type=refresh_token" \ --data-urlencode "refresh_token={refresh-token}" "https://iam.bluemix.net/identity/token"`

I expect to get refresh token but get error {"context":"requestId":"021c3482...""},"errorCode":"BXNIM0507E","errorMessage":"For OpenID Connect related APIs, you need to send your client credentials as basic authorization header"}

Can some one help me in understanding what is going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description in https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/watson?topic=watson-iam is incorrectly describing the refresh case. I will follow-up with the docs team to update that section.
This is the generic description how to get tokens for API keys:
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/iam?topic=iam-iamtoken_from_apikey

For API usage, IBM Cloud allows you to generate access token's without providing a client id / secret. In this case, a `default` client id is assumed which is only allowed to create tokens for API keys, but not authorized to use any other grant type - including the grant_type `refresh_token`. Therefore, simply dismiss the refresh token from the response of the API key grant in the first call - you won't be able to use it.

In the API key use case, there is no benefit of using the grant_type `refresh_token` over getting a new access token with the API key grant type anyway - all validation steps that are done internally (does the user stil exist / is the user still in the account / ...) are identical. But the refresh token eventually will expire - the API key not.

Comment: Thanks Martin. So what I understand is we cannot use 'refresh token'. Once 'access token' expires after one hour, we need to regenerate access token and use the new 'access token' for further requests and so on. Is my understanding correct ?