# IBM Cloud auth refresh_token to refresh expired access_token?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-speech, ibm-cloud-iam

IBM Cloud auth bearer tokens (`access_token`) expire in one hour. Two questions:

Is there a specific error message that signals that the `access_token` has expired? Not the general error message `HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available`. Specifically, does the Speech-to-Text SDK send a message here

```js
stream.on('message', function(message, data) {
```

when the `access_token` has expired?

Second question: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56378815/unable-to-generate-refresh-token-for-ibm-visual-recognition-api/56384988#56384988) says that

> there is no benefit of using the grant_type refresh_token over getting
>   a new access token

To confirm that I understand that, the `refresh_token` should never be used; I should just get a new `access_token`?

Comment: Are you using any SDK? They have authenticators, e.g. the Node SDK: https://github.com/IBM/node-sdk-core/blob/master/AUTHENTICATION.md

Comment: I'm using the Speech-Javascript-SDK. The documentation is here: http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/speech-javascript-sdk/master/RecognizeStream.html. There is a `message` event but it doesn't say what the messages are.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [IAMAuthenticator](https://github.com/IBM/node-sdk-core/blob/master/AUTHENTICATION.md) to handle everything. See the [up-to-date Speech documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text/speech-to-text?code=node#authentication) here. You linked to [RecognizeStream](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text/speech-to-text?code=node#websocket_methods) which seems to be deprecated.

There is an example on how to use the IAMAuthenticator for the initial authentication. That object then handles the refresh automatically.